# Parallel processing isn't working with multi cores in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, intel, cpu, multi-core

My laptop has 4 cores.

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           61
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:                        4
CPU MHz:                         800.490
CPU max MHz:                     3000.0000
CPU min MHz:                     500.0000
BogoMIPS:                        4788.65
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       64 KiB
L2 cache:                        512 KiB
L3 cache:                        4 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cach
                                 e flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB condit
                                 ional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx f
                                 xsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rd
                                 tscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_
                                 good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmper
                                 f pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est t
                                 m2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 ss
                                 e4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes
                                  xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetc
                                 h cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs 
                                 ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpi
                                 d ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi
                                 2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap intel_pt xsaveop
                                 t dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
```

but while I using in parallel computing it shows a message

```
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 4
slots that were requested by the application:

  fireFoam

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots
available for use.

A "slot" is the Open MPI term for an allocatable unit where we can
launch a process.  The number of slots available are defined by the
environment in which Open MPI processes are run:

  1. Hostfile, via "slots=N" clauses (N defaults to number of
     processor cores if not provided)
  2. The --host command line parameter, via a ":N" suffix on the
     hostname (N defaults to 1 if not provided)
  3. Resource manager (e.g., SLURM, PBS/Torque, LSF, etc.)
  4. If none of a hostfile, the --host command line parameter, or an
     RM is present, Open MPI defaults to the number of processor cores

In all the above cases, if you want Open MPI to default to the number
of hardware threads instead of the number of processor cores, use the
--use-hwthread-cpus option.

Alternatively, you can use the --oversubscribe option to ignore the
number of available slots when deciding the number of processes to
launch.
```

Comment: Your LapTop does not have 4 cores, it has 2 cores and 2 thread per core for a total of 4 CPUs. Did you use `--use-hwthread-cpus` option?

Comment: --use-hwthread-cpus: command not found
How can I use it?